# Devolver numero y sucesivos con backtracing - PROLOG

Tags: prolog

El predicado que quiero implementar necesito que haga lo siguiente:

```
predicado(Máximo,Num1,Num2).
```

Y debe devolver dos números Num1 y Num2 cumpliendose que:

- Num1 < Num2
- Num2 <= Máximo

A continuación dejo algunos ejemplos para que se comprenda mejor:

```
predicado(1,Num1,Num2).
false

predicado(2,Num1,Num2).
Num1=1,Num2=2;
false

predicado(3,Num1,Num2).
Num1=1,Num2=2;
Num1=1,Num2=3;
Num1=2,Num2=3;
false

predicado(4,Num1,Num2).
Num1=1,Num2=2;
Num1=1,Num2=3;
Num1=1,Num2=4;
Num1=2,Num2=3;
Num1=2,Num2=4;
Num1=3,Num2=4;
false
```

Y así sucesivamente.

He desarrollado un código para intentar solucionarlo, es el siguiente:

```
obtener_numerosSwap(NRegs,NRegs2,NRegs):-
    NRegs>1,
    NRegs2 is NRegs-1.

obtener_numerosSwap(N2,N1,N2) :-
    N2 > 1,
    Nnew is N2-1,
    obtener_numerosSwap(Nnew,N1,Nnew).

obtener_numerosSwap(NRegs,N1,N2) :-
    var(N2),
    NRegs > 1,
    N2 is NRegs-1,
    obtener_numerosSwap(N2,N1,N2).
```

Dejo algunos ejemplos de su ejecución. Quiero aclarar que funciona para N<=3, pero eso no está bien.

```
1 ?- obtener_numerosSwap(1,A,B).
false.

2 ?- obtener_numerosSwap(2,A,B).
A = 1,
B = 2 ;
false.

3 ?- obtener_numerosSwap(3,A,B).
A = 2,
B = 3 ;
A = 1,
B = 3 ;
A = 1,
B = 2 ;
false.
```

También recalcar que da igual que no salgan ordenados y, que como ya he dicho antes, es necesario que funcione por backtracking, es decir, que cada vez que de ; me devuelva una solución.

A continuación os enseño como para N>3 no funciona:

```
4 ?- obtener_numerosSwap(4,A,B).
A = 3,
B = 4 ;
A = 2,
B = 4 ;
A = 1,
B = 4 ;
A = 2,
B = 3 ;
A = 1,
B = 3 ;
false.
```

Sé donde está el fallo, y es que en el tercer predicado de obtener_numerosSwap hace el decremento de NRegs, pero solo funciona cuando el N2 no está instanciado y la resta es true. El problema es que no se como solucionarlo.

Gracias de ante mano a cualquier ayuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente necesitas una función que genere un rango de números por reevaluación:

```
ran(X,Y,X) :- X < Y.
ran(X,Y,Z) :- X < Y, X2 is X+1, ran(X2,Y,Z).
```

Ahora puedes implementar tu predicado en base a dos rangos:

- De `1` al máximo (`X+1`), que será el segundo número (`Z`)
- De `1` a `Z`, que será el primer número (`Y`)

Es decir:

```
p(X,Y,Z) :- X2 is X+1, ran(1,X2,Z), ran(1,Z,Y).
```